# Bypass Base or Generic exception

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception

In my framework, I am exposing a method to user which raises a custom exception and handling it in framework if raised.
But user has used generic catch block (Exception or except) while using my method, thus it is not handled as expected.

Is there any way I can solve this issue either by ,
i) Making my custom exception bypass generic except block (or get caught only by my custom except block).
ii) get the flow back to test_driver directly when condition is encountered.

Note: I can not restrict user to using generic catch block.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to bypass a `try ... except`. Every exception that can be thrown can also be caught with an `except`. That's the whole point of exception handling.

Trying to bypass an exception handler is not the correct solution. If your user catches your exception, there's nothing you can do about it. Look at it this way: The user caught an exception that he wasn't supposed to catch. This is a bug in the user's code. The correct way to deal with bugs is to fix them, not try to bypass them. It's not your responsibility to do anything about this problem - it's the user's responsibility to fix that bug.

Comment: Using bare except is not a suggested practice but users may use it based on their use case. As a framework provider, I do not want to enforce that restriction on them.

Comment: @user3710769 Forcing your users to write correct code is not a restriction in any way. Like I said, there's nothing you can do about it. A bug is a bug, and has to be fixed.

Comment: any idea on how these scenarios are been handled in other frameworks ?

Comment: @RaghavendraB I don't know what your framework is doing and what it's using that exception for, so I can't tell you if there are any alternatives. But other frameworks that throw exceptions for communication don't handle the "problem" of the user catching that exception at all. If the user does something stupid that breaks the framework, it's their own problem.